# why regexp behave diffrently in GSHEETS and GOOGLE DOCS

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have the following text in the body of a GDOCS document

```
 Paris le ${date}
```

where as in google Sheets the formula

```
=REGEXREPLACE( D2;"\$\{date\}";"03/05/20")
```

gives the desired result.
the script in GDOCS does not replace the string ${date}

```
function test(){
var monDocument=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var docBody=monDocument.getBody();
docBody.replaceText("\$\{date\}","03/05/20");
// does not replace the string
}
```

I tried replacing Paris instead of ${date} and it worked
Please do not propose any workaround (I tried and they work). I need to understand my mistake

Comment: Might be an escaping issue. Try `\\$` instead of `\$`, does that fix it?

Comment: Yes TheMaster it is the solution Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you CertainPerformance that was the solution
It was an escaping issue. Trying \$ instead of \$ fixed it